# Couldn't initialize guard-livereload on ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby, guard, livereload

When I tried to initalize with

```
guard --debug
```

the following error occured.

```
For a better Pry experience on Windows, please use ansicon:
   http://adoxa.3eeweb.com/ansicon/
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
21:14:45 - INFO - You must 'gem install win32console' to use color on Windows
21:14:45 - ERROR - Could not load 'guard/livereload' or find class Guard::Livere
load
21:14:45 - ERROR - C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems
/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/ker
nel_require.rb:126:in `require'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.5.3-
x86-mingw32/lib/ruby_http_parser.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/ker
nel_require.rb:135:in `require'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/ker
nel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/ker
nel_require.rb:144:in `require'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.5.3-
x86-mingw32/lib/http_parser.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/ker
nel_require.rb:135:in `require'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/ker
nel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/ker
nel_require.rb:144:in `require'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.5.3-
x86-mingw32/lib/http/parser.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/ker
nel_require.rb:73:in `require'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/ker
nel_require.rb:73:in `require'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/em-websocket-0.5.0/li
b/em-websocket/handshake.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/ker
nel_require.rb:73:in `require'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/ker
nel_require.rb:73:in `require'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/em-websocket-0.5.0/li
b/em-websocket.rb:15:in `block in <top (required)>'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/em-websocket-0.5.0/li
b/em-websocket.rb:14:in `each'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/em-websocket-0.5.0/li
b/em-websocket.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/ker
nel_require.rb:73:in `require'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/ker
nel_require.rb:73:in `require'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-livereload-2.1.
2/lib/guard/livereload/websocket.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/ker
nel_require.rb:73:in `require'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/ker
nel_require.rb:73:in `require'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-livereload-2.1.
2/lib/guard/livereload.rb:6:in `<class:LiveReload>'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-livereload-2.1.
2/lib/guard/livereload.rb:5:in `<module:Guard>'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-livereload-2.1.
2/lib/guard/livereload.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/ker
nel_require.rb:135:in `require'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/ker
nel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/ker
nel_require.rb:144:in `require'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.6.0/lib/guard
/plugin_util.rb:100:in `plugin_class'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.6.0/lib/guard
/plugin_util.rb:57:in `initialize_plugin'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.6.0/lib/guard
.rb:167:in `add_plugin'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.6.0/lib/guard
/dsl.rb:174:in `block in guard'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.6.0/lib/guard
/dsl.rb:173:in `each'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.6.0/lib/guard
/dsl.rb:173:in `guard'
> [#] C:/Users/ZAW OO/Desktop/work/Guardfile:39:in `_instance_eval_guardfile'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.6.0/lib/guard
/guardfile/evaluator.rb:97:in `instance_eval'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.6.0/lib/guard
/guardfile/evaluator.rb:97:in `_instance_eval_guardfile'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.6.0/lib/guard
/guardfile/evaluator.rb:37:in `evaluate_guardfile'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.6.0/lib/guard
/setuper.rb:146:in `evaluate_guardfile'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.6.0/lib/guard
/setuper.rb:64:in `setup'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.6.0/lib/guard
/commander.rb:24:in `start'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.6.0/lib/guard
/cli.rb:107:in `start'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/
command.rb:27:in `run'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/
invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.
rb:359:in `dispatch'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/
base.rb:440:in `start'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.6.0/bin/guard
:6:in `<top (required)>'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/guard:23:in `load'
> [#] C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/guard:23:in `<main>'
21:14:45 - ERROR - Invalid Guardfile, original error is:
> [#] undefined method `superclass' for nil:NilClass
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.6.0/lib/guard/plugi
n_util.rb:57:in `initialize_plugin': undefined method `superclass' for nil:NilCl
ass (NoMethodError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.6.0/li
b/guard.rb:167:in `add_plugin'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.6.0/li
b/guard/dsl.rb:174:in `block in guard'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.6.0/li
b/guard/dsl.rb:173:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.6.0/li
b/guard/dsl.rb:173:in `guard'
        from C:/Users/ZAW OO/Desktop/work/Guardfile:39:in `_instance_eval_guardf
ile'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.6.0/li
b/guard/guardfile/evaluator.rb:97:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.6.0/li
b/guard/guardfile/evaluator.rb:97:in `_instance_eval_guardfile'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.6.0/li
b/guard/guardfile/evaluator.rb:37:in `evaluate_guardfile'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.6.0/li
b/guard/setuper.rb:146:in `evaluate_guardfile'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.6.0/li
b/guard/setuper.rb:64:in `setup'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.6.0/li
b/guard/commander.rb:24:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.6.0/li
b/guard/cli.rb:107:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/li
b/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/li
b/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/li
b/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.6.0/bi
n/guard:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/guard:23:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/guard:23:in `<main>'
```

here is my guard file

```
# A sample Guardfile
# More info at https://github.com/guard/guard#readme

guard 'sass', :input => 'sass', :output => 'css'

guard 'livereload' do
    watch(%r{.+\.(css|html|js)$})
end
```

But When I leave blank for livereload part in guardfile, It work as normal. I also tried to install Win32console but package isn't present and later I found out it doesn't need for ruby 2. I run guard under ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14) [i386-mingw32] on 64bit (Window 7).

Comment: I assume you installed the livereload gem? https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload

Comment: Yes I already installed it. also checked with gem list, version is 2.1.2

Comment: Random guess #1: https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload/issues/72

Something wrong with your Gemfile maybe? I couldn't find anything else. Perhaps try and completely uninstall livereload and install a new copy of the latest gem?

Comment: Well, for now, there is no gemfile in my project directory, I just followed this tutorials, code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/guard-is-your-best-friend--net-31021. I'm pretty new to ruby

Comment: My apologies, I assumed you were using Rails. Do you know if the gem that was installed is available to the user that's executing the Ruby code? Are you using RVM? `gem list -l` to see if all gems are installed.

Comment: Nevermind and thank you. I'm using Railsinstaller because I am on windows. When I checked with "gem list -1", all of guard plugins including guard-livereload was installed.

Comment: I think it'd make sense for you to post your Guardfile code as well.

Comment: Like other before, I would love to see the relevant parts of your Guardfile and if you use bundler, your Gemfile as well.

Comment: Updated. Since I didn't use with bundler, there is no Gemfile in my directory